# Git repository structure and workflow for concurrent development life-cycle environments

Tags: git, workflow

I want a several different versions of my code, at different stages of its development life-cycle, to be version controlled and live on the web concurrently at all times. Versions are typically named *development*, *staging* and *live* and are structured as in the following tree.

```
Sitename
  |--Development
  |--Live
  `--Staging
```

- Is it better to create three separate repositories or one
  repository with three branches permanently checked out?
- What are the respective merits and demerits of each workflow?
- Being new to Git, how do I implement the preferred workflow?

---

### Addendum

I'd prefer to create a single repository but that would mean creating the repository under `Sitename` and having three working directories within it, however my understanding is that Git does not support nested working directories. I'm aware of a contributed solution called `git-new-workdir` but have read that new users could suffer more consequences than benefits using this workflow so I'm interested in alternatives.

Comment: I suggest you have a read through this: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Comment: @Greg Hewgill I have already read this.

Comment: Those are branches of the same repository, so I wouldn't create individual repositories for each one.

Comment: I have evolved nvie's model to allow removal of features quickly with no development intervention. I also don't recommend back-merges as you don't have the freedom to remove the complete feature. Sometimes it's ok as long as there are no effects to the end user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old question but still gets many views so I think it deserves a proper answer. When I asked this question I was familiar with SVN but new to Git, but now, three years later, I feel qualified to answer it.

The most pertinent part of this question is:

> Is it better to create three separate repositories or one repository with three branches permanently checked out?

If one had to choose between these two options it would be the latter but the correct answer is *neither!* It is just as incorrect to create different repositories for different environments as it is to create different branches for different environments.

The correct way to use Git is to just have one repository for one project. The repository can be cloned as many times as needed. Just as different users can check out different version of the code, so too can different environments have different versions of the code checked out from their copy of the repository. Different environments can be though of as just different users of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Keep one repository. Come up with a convention for branches. Usually it's this:

**master**: represents the code that is running on the servers and what your users experience

**staging**: (optional) represents the code deployed to your staging servers and what your select beta testers use.

**release-candidate or RC**: all features that have been tested alone and together with other features and have passed. This could be merged to master and/or staging at any time.

**integration or dev**: all features past and present (complete and incomplete) integrated to get feedback as to what is failing now.

**feature or task**: (usually named as the ticket number) houses a feature - preferably started from a common point as other features in an iteration.

I recommend this workflow for managing them: http://dymitruk.com/blog/2012/02/05/branch-per-feature/

Nothing is written in stone, just make sure you are organized and consistent and do what makes sense for your team.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can achieve this with git post check-in
 hooks. I would look at a real build server solution (e.g. TeamCity, FinalBuilder). The build server watches your repository on three different branches and then deploys them where you want them to.